# What is the maximum likelihood of a binomial distribution?

Tags: parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

i've looked everywhere I could for an answer to this question but no luck !
If I have $X_1 .... X_n$ random variables that are independent and identically distributed such as ∀ $1 <$ $i$ $<n$, $X_i$ ~ B(n,$\theta$) (binomial distribution)

I know that the likelihood is :

$P_n$($\theta$,x)=$\prod\limits_{i}$ $\binom{n}{x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$

but then it seems kind of hard to calculate as product, I tried to calculate log($p_n$) but then the $x_i$! causes me problems

Can you enlighten me ? what is the max-likelihood of a binomial distribution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the log-likelihood function, i.e.
$$L(p) = \log \prod_i \binom{n}{x_i} p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$$
which becomes
$$L(p) =  \sum_i \log\binom{n}{x_i} p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$$
even more
$$L(p) =  \sum_i \log\binom{n}{x_i} +  \sum_i x_i\log p +  \sum_i(n-x_i)\log(1-p)$$
Since you're interested in the ML estimate of $p$. let's derive with respect to $p$ and set it to zero. 
$$\frac{d}{dp}L(p) = \frac{1}{p}\sum_i x_i -   \frac{1}{1-p}\sum_i(n-x_i) = 0$$
which gives you
$$\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_i(n-x_i) = \frac{1}{p}\sum_i x_i$$
or
$$\frac{\sum_i(n-x_i)}{\sum_i x_i} = \frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{1}{p} - 1$$
Now find $p$.
$$\frac{1}{p}  = \frac{\sum_i(n-x_i) + \sum_i x_i}{\sum_i x_i} = \frac{\sum_i n}{\sum_i x_i} $$

Comment: thank you, it was just a matter of concentration and calculating step by step